# If statement not working inside view

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, if-statement

I have an if statement inside of my razor view that does not work and I can't figure out why:

```
@If Html.DisplayFor(Function(m) CDate(m.PS.DateStart).Month) Is "" Then
                @<p></p>
Else
                @<p>@Html.DisplayFor(Function(m) CDate(m.PS.DateStart).Month)/@Html.DisplayFor(Function(m) CDate(m.PS.DateStart).Day)/@Html.DisplayFor(Function(m) CDate(m.PS.DateStart).Year)</p>
End If
```

What I can tell from the Debug is no matter what the `@IF` statement returns the `ELSE` statement.  I've tried setting the statement like this

```
@If Html.DisplayFor(Function(m) CDate(m.PS.DateStart).Month) Is Nothing Then
```

But it still returns the `ELSE` statement.

I've also tried if statements similar to

```
@If IsNothing(Model.PS.DateStart) Then
  @<p></p>
Else
  @<p>@Html.DisplayFor(Function(m) m.PS.DateStart)</p>  
End If
```

And I get an error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Because nothing has been passed to my model yet.

Comment: Can you just check the model, without checking Html.DisplayFor?  i.e., `@If CDate(m.PS.DateStart).Month IS ""`

Comment: Are you trying to verify that m.PS.DateStart has a value?

Comment: @Tom No I cannot just check the model this is populated after the user fills out a textbox

Comment: @Nick I am trying to tell it IF there is a value then This if there isnt a value then Nothing

Comment: So you are just trying to verify that a user filled out a text box?

Comment: Well then that sounds like your problem.  If the model doesn't exist yet, how do you expect the code to get anywhere besides the else block?  If you're trying to check whether a textbox has a date value, it sounds like you're looking for javascript validation

Comment: @Nick Yes and if they have return a value.  If they haven't Return nothing.

Comment: @Tom That's why I'm using the DisplayFor attribute, because if there is no value it returns nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired By @Nick 's comments here is the solution:

```
@If Html.DisplayFor(Function(m) m.PS.DateStart).ToString = "" Then
 @<p></p>
Else
 @<p>@Html.DisplayFor(Function(m) CDate(m.PS.DateStart).Month)/@Html.DisplayFor(Function(m) CDate(m.PS.DateStart).Day)/@Html.DisplayFor(Function(m) CDate(m.PS.DateStart).Year)</p>
End If
```